# Documentation for quickly widgets?

Tags: application-development, quickly, widgets

I tried to use the quickly.widgets.text_editor class in a quickly project just now (as in one of the highlighted quickly tutorials) and got an import error. When I tried to inspect the quickly.widgets module I got an import error. Does quickly still include its own widgets? Does it still include the text_editor widget? There doesn't seem to be any coherent API documentation for quickly on the Ubuntu developers site! (Sorry if I'm just missing something obvious.) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you maybe don't have the quickly-widgets package installed.

`sudo apt-get install quickly-widgets`

Then, e.g. following this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urwBBlYhaUU&feature=player_embedded, the imports seems to work fine.

As far as docs go, the best I could find is using pythons internal documentation system.

```
from quickly.widgets import text_editor
print text_editor.__doc__
```

> ```
> Module for the TextView widgth wich encapsulates management of TextBuffer
> and TextIter for common functionality, such as cut, copy, paste, undo, redo, 
> and highlighting of text.
>
> Using
> #create the TextEditor and set the text
> editor = TextEditor()
> editor.text = "Text to add to the editor"
>
> #use cut, works the same for copy, paste, undo, and redo
> def __handle_on_cut(self, widget, data=None):
>     self.editor.cut()
>
> #add string to highlight
> self.editor.add_highlight("Ubuntu")
> self.editor.add_highlight("Quickly")
>
> #remove highlights
> self.editor.clear_highlight("Ubuntu")
> self.editor.clear_all_highlight()
>
> Configuring
> #Configure as a TextView
> self.editor.set_wrap_mode(Gtk.WRAP_CHAR)
>
> #Access the Gtk.TextBuffer if needed
> buffer = self.editor.get_buffer()
>
> Extending
> A TextEditor is Gtk.TextView
> ```

Comment: Thanks trent. I somehow missed the fact that the widgets were a separate package. Once I installed it everything worked fine.